What does "coaxing" mean?
I want to ask "coaxing" means in this sentence and context

Cellular ag is best known for generating living cells (like muscle or skin cells) that can proliferate and become food or clothing. Acellular ag entails coaxing living, microscopic organisms, like yeast, bacteria, algae, or fungi, to produce specific organic molecules such as
fats and proteins that aren’t actually alive themselves. In acellular ag, since you’re starting with just yeast or some other microorganism as opposed to a biopsy from an actual animal, there’s no animal involved in the making of these animal products.


Hello Le Minh,  When asking for the meaning of a word, please first use a dictionary, and then explain why you think the dictionary definition doesn't help you.

Dear James K. Off course, I've used dictionary but its meaning is incorrect with this context, so I have to ask it here. If not, why I ask?

Please demonstrate the use of a dictionary.  I am not a mind reader.  I don't know what the dictionary definition that you have read says.  Please include this information.  Are you familiar with the idea of "extended meaning"?  Which dictionary did you use?

Merriam-Webster has "to manipulate with great perseverance and usually with considerable effort toward a desired state or activity coax a fire to burn;
is optimistic that stem cells can be coaxed into growing into replacement tissue for failing organs". Did not do the research.

Cambridge Advanced Learners has "to manage to get something to do something, or something to happen, by being very patient and taking great care: ... Stem cells are coaxed to grow into a variety of cells that can be injected into patients. / She coaxed the plane in for the landing."

The point of the requirements about dictionaries, and about showing what you found, is that the dictionary itself must have been confusing or unclear to you. If you tell about that confusion or unclearness, then answers can address them, and those will be much more helpful answers than "Well, it means what it means." Please use the "edit" button under the question to tell more about what you found.

Dear James K and Stuart F, thanks for your comments. I'm a translator, from English to Vietnamese. I've used many dictionaries for work. Whenever I can't understand any word or phrase meaning, I'll ask some English forums. I often ask a general question because I want to hear/to know all way of understanding about this word/phrase. I respect the diverse thinking so I don't share my thinking first, I prefer to listen and choose the best answer for me in the specific context I knew.

Coax takes the usual meaning:

If you coax someone into doing something, you gently try to persuade them to do it.

Here the coaxing is not literal persuasion but other forms of stimulations to make the organisms produce the specific organic molecules.
Collins Dictionary's sense 1 verb for coax
